# Why is validate defunct in r shiny?

Tags: r, validation, shiny

I am trying to include a `validate` in my Shiny App to display an error message when the inputs selected lead to an empty data frame.

```
# Function to construct df used in the plot
df_construction <- function(selected_month, selected_variable){
airquality %>%
    dplyr::filter(Month == selected_month,
                  !is.na(!!rlang::sym(selected_variable)))%>%
    select(Month, Day, selected_variable)
}

# Populate df with the inputs selected
df1 <- reactive({
       df_construction(input$month_select, selected_variable())
        })

# Plot
output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    validate(
            need(
                expr = !empty(df1()), 
                message = "There is no data for this Month-variable combination. \n Please make a different choice.")
        )

  plots <- double_plotting(input$month_select, selected_variable()) # This is a function to plot
        plots
    })
```

`input$month_select` comes from a `pickerInput` and `selected_variable()` is a reactive switch, where the input is a `pickerInput` too.

I am getting the following error:

```
Warning: Error in : 'validate' is defunct.
Use 'geojsonlint::geojson_lint()' instead.
See help("Defunct")
```

I have tried using geojson_lint but without success.

Comment: Its hard to tell since your example isn't reproducible, but are you sure you're calling Shiny's `validate` and not another packages (like `jsonlite`?). What happens if you change `validate` to `shiny::validate`?

Comment: I think you are right! I no longer get the same error but get `invalid type/length (symbol/0) in vector allocation` instead.

Comment: Not sure whats going on there sorry. tbh, given this is no longer about validate being defunct, I recommend you rework this question to focus on the new problem, and if you can, make it a reproducible app so we can run it and see the error